# How to link URLs in SEO when we upgrade code from jQuery to angularjs

Tags: angularjs, seo

When we update our code from jQuery to angular our URLs changed. So how to link previous URLs to new ones for SEO?

For example:
We have `https://example.com/newPage` in jquery and in angular it updates to `https://example.com/#newPage`. So when I search in Google `newPage` comes on top. How can we link these two URLs so that after upgrade to angular the Search engine result does not change and the page has the same rank?

Comment: welcome to SO, please look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO